# etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid scrolling issue

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

I am using the etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid for the staggeredGrid view. I am facing very strage issue if i have one item in the gird and try to scroll down and up, I don't see the list item at all. Can you please provide any help if someone aware about the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please check : https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/issues/176

Comment: Hi,if you want to fix this , we have only one solution for now  please check offsetChildrenTopAndBottom and put a getchildcount condtion >1 so it won't add the offset.

Comment: Excellent,Yes it's working for me thanks lot for suggestion, I also post peace of where check this condition again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**StaggeredGridView.class**

Just try to adding this `getChildCount()>1` condition :

```
protected void offsetChildrenTopAndBottom(final int offset, final int column) {
    if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "offsetChildrenTopAndBottom: " + offset + " column:" + column);
     if(getChildCount()>1) {
            final int count = getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final View v = getChildAt(i);
                if (v != null &&
                        v.getLayoutParams() != null &&
                        v.getLayoutParams() instanceof GridLayoutParams) {
                    GridLayoutParams lp = (GridLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                    if (lp.column == column) {
                        v.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
                    }
                }
            }
            offsetColumnTopAndBottom(offset, column);
        }
    }
```